# CouchBase lite; can not synchronize data

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase-lite

I am using `CoachBase lite` on `Android` against `CouchDB` . Today (yesterday was fine) I can not synchronize data between my CouchDB an my device but it only happens with my device, the rest works well, I am getting this issue on my `Android`:

> 12-06 12:51:11.574 E/RemoteRequest: io exception.  url:
>   http://x.x.x.x:5984/DB/_session
>                                       org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /x.x.x.x:5984
>   timed out
>                                           at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:126)
>                                           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
>                                           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
>                                           at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
>                                           at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
>                                           at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:591)
>                                           at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:512)
>                                           at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:490)
>                                           at com.couchbase.lite.support.RemoteRequest.executeRequest(RemoteRequest.java:184)
>                                           at com.couchbase.lite.support.RemoteRequest.run(RemoteRequest.java:103)
>                                           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
>                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
>                                           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
>                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)

If I tab on:

> E/RemoteRequest: io exception. url: http://x.x.x.x:5984/DB/_session

I get:

> {"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not authorized to access
>   this db."}

This my user json on `CouchDB`

```
{
   "_id": "40bbdbf8f260ce043622550c55b667a0",
   "_rev": "20-28c1edf0fd20ec4a77bb76ac84a426c8",
   "type": "user",
   "id": 2309,
   "username": "aprs",
   "password": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
   "name": "My mane",
   "id_company": 9,
   "id_technician": null,
   "id_worker": null,
   "version": "0x0000000025919D4C",
   "ismaster": true
}
```

any clue about what happen?

Comment: The error says the connection timed out.  The problem could happen for a half dozen reasons.  Did you try connecting to the db using a tool like cURL?

Comment: @Hod No I dont. I am going to install  cURL on my Windows...and then? How I can get where is the error

Comment: I'd start with simple document operations via REST, and make sure auth is working.  Which version of CouchDB are you using?

Comment: I am using CouchDB 1.6.1 . simple document operations ?¿ what do you mean?

Comment: Using cURL to read and write documents.  Check this link for examples: https://blog.couchbase.com/getting-comfortable-with-couchbase-mobile-sync-gateway-via-the-command-line/